# innerHTML output with Javascript template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, templates, bluetooth-lowenergy

For my project I have to scan BLE-tags and show their RSSI for proximity.

The output of the BLEs is working with a JavaScript template.

```
  <body>
     <div id="header" data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <h1>BLE overview</h1>
     </div>          
        </br>
     <div data-role="content" id="home">
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-inline="true" class="pure-button initialize">Initialize</a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-inline="true" class="pure-button startScan">Start Scan</a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-inline="true" class="pure-button stopScan">Stop Scan</a>
     </div>
        <ul data-role="list-view" class="devices"></ul>
     <div data-role="content id="result">
       <script type="text/template" id="device">     //start of the schript tag and output of the scanned BLEs
          <ul data-role="listview">
             <li data-address="{0}">
                <h2>{1}</h2>
                <a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="b" class="pure-button connect">Connect</a>
                <div id="rssiop"> RSSI:  <div>   // value of the RSSI
                </br>   
            </li> 
         </ul>
      </script> 
   </div>
```

The function, which return the value of the rssi is following

```
 function startScanSuccess(obj)
{
  console.log("The RSSI value is:" + obj.rssi);  // here I see the RSSI value on the console

  if (obj.status == "scanResult")
  {
    console.log("Scan Result");

    addDevice(obj.address, obj.name);         
  }
  else if (obj.status == "scanStarted")
  {
    console.log("Scan Started");
  }
  else
  {
    console.log("Unexpected Start Scan Status");
  }
}
```

and this is the function which gives the name and address of the scanned BLE out

```
function addDevice(address, name)
{
  var $devices = $(".devices");

  var $check = $devices.find("li[data-address='{0}']".format(address));

  if ($check.length > 0)
  {
    return;

  }
  console.log("Mein RSSI: " + obj.rssi);
  document.getElementById("rssiop").innerHTML = "The RSSI value is:";
  var template = $("#device").text().format(address, name);

  $devices.append(template);   
}
```

So everything is working and when I put the div-tag above the template script I can see the RSSI. Can anyone figure out why the innerHTML is in the template part not working?

Comment: What constitutes not working?

Comment: The part with the innerHTML, because the script tag is type template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out:

The Problem was that the innerHTML wasn't working, because I used the append()-command for the list output. I just had to add the rssi parameter to the addDevices function and it worked.

The correct code of the addDevice function:

```
function addDevice(address, name, rssi)
{
  var $devices = $(".devices");

  var $check = $devices.find("li[data-address='{0}']".format(address));

  if ($check.length > 0)
  {
    return;

  }
  var template = $("#device").text().format(address, name, rssi);

  $devices.append(template);

}
```